# Using Python for web scraping

Tags: python, translation, wikipedia

I need to use a specific website (Translates English to my language) in my python code , and also I don't wanna use googletrans in python , it's huge load of data , so I need to use python for doing it fast , Is there any references or any title than I can read about it ? or any doc in python ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using selenium or BeautifulSoup for interacting with a website or web scraping, but if you simply want to open a website you could use the webbrowser module.

```
import webbrowser

Google = 'https://www.google.com/?safe=active&safe=active'

webbrowser.open(Google)
```

Here are some links to selenium and BeautifulSoup

https://pythonspot.com/selenium-webdriver/

https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/

Hope this helps.